# $(this).children / find is not working

Tags: jquery, find, this, children

I got a very simple code that should work. I can't understand why is not working.

I have:

```
<div class="mix category-1" onmouseover="showdescrmini()">
          <img src="large-464x400.jpeg" class="coverimgminipost">
          <h2 class="miniposttitle">Title</h2>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
function showdescrmini()
        {
         $(this).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
        }
```

I already tried:

```
function showdescrmini()
        {
         $(this).find('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
        }
```

If I put an alert() in the script, it appears when the mouse is over, so the problem is that single line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, `this` points to `window`, not div element. Use `onmouseover="showdescrmini(this)"` and your function should look like this:

```
function showdescrmini(div)
{
         $(div).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
}
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers! I'm not that pro in JQuery/Javascript, and this things sometimes just go away through my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //In html you should pass this in function

      <div class="mix category-1" onmouseover="showdescrmini(this)">
             <img src="large-464x400.jpeg" class="coverimgminipost">
             <h2 class="miniposttitle">Title</h2>
      </div>

      //in javascript accept this as parameter thisObj
     function showdescrmini(thisObj)
     {
        $(thisObj).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a parameter in your function like below and then where you call the function target which want to perform the function for where you use `this` as the current element:

script...

```
function showdescrmini(target)
{
         $(target).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
}
```

html...

```
<div class="mix category-1" onmouseover="showdescrmini(this)">
          <img src="large-464x400.jpeg" class="coverimgminipost">
          <h2 class="miniposttitle">Title</h2>
</div>
```

---

But I would recommend you not to use inline javascript and so far for this use like this in your js script file:

```
$('.mix.category-1').hover(function(){
      $(this).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I´m gonna use other code, but I was trying this first, isolating the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in the function `$(this)` is point to DOM root

Try this

```
$(".mix.category-1").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).children('.miniposttitle').css('color','red');
});
```

`$(this)` is point to your target element